# No Output for Preamp circuit in TINA

Tags: operational-amplifier, preamp, ne5532

Is this a spice problem or a design(me) problem?  The rails are producing the expected 9 and -9 volts, but nothing is coming through on the output. I haven't ever done op amps without a bias voltage though so it's very possible that I've got something obvious wrong. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The op-amps still need a bias, in this case to ground.

Connect a 330k resistor from U1 IN+ to ground to provide the bias current required. It will then set the input bias voltage to 0V. The output midpoint will also be 0v. This will supply the bias requirement for the second op-amp.

R8 and R9 are not required. They just take up space.

If you were going for a gain of 34 per stage, then R8 and R9 should be on the IN- of their respective amplifiers.

Comment: Thanks!  I guess I got a little flipped around.  Didn't realize it wouldn't be biased though!